# Could Java be used to write a Win32 System Service?

Tags: java, winapi, jabaco

The title sort of sums it up. I was thinking of using [Jabaco](http://www.jabaco.org) seeing as it makes .EXEs (as well as .jar files), and I'm more familiar with VB syntax than with Java.

Comment: I you're more familiar with VB than with Java, and you want to create a windows service, why don't you use VB.Net?

Comment: Partly because I don't know VB.Net, partly because I want to get to know Jabaco, and partly masochism ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could certainly do this with the [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org/doc/english/download.jsp). I'm not familiar with Jabaco, but I wouldn't be at all surprised if you can simply reference the Jabaco runtime from the Java Service Wrapper. It's a pretty trivial tool to use, and the free variant should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Also, there is a java specific win32 service wrapper: [JSL](http://jslwin.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you could java directly to create a service, but you can use srvany.exe to run any program as a service.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890

Answer (score 1):

Jpackages dot com have a product called execJ which does exactly that.

I also found an article about how to do it differently [here](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=java&seqNum=13).