# How do I setup a standalone java application to run as a service using procrun?

Tags: java, procrun, apache-commons-daemon

I'm trying to setup a standalone java service using [commons-daemon (procrun)](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/procrun.html)

Does anyone know where to get procrun and how to get it up and running?

Are there any alternatives? (I would use Java Service Wrapper but I can't use GPL Licensed code)

Comment: I found this guide and was able to get it working. I had to download tomcat and copy the tomcat.exe and tomcatw.exe to another directory and rename them. Those files are "procrun".

http://blog.platinumsolutions.com/node/234

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624841/could-java-be-used-to-write-a-win32-system-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page does contain the download.

http://www.apache.org/dist/commons/daemon/binaries/windows/

This page tells you what you need.

http://commons.apache.org/daemon/binaries.html

Answer (score 2):

The procrun binaries are hard to find, but they can be located [here](http://www.apache.org/dist/commons/daemon/binaries/windows/) in case anyone else is looking for them.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you can't run "Java Service Wrapper" because its GPL.  You didn't provide a link, but there is [JSL](http://jslwin.sourceforge.net) which isn't GPL (according to their license page).  I have used this in the distant past.

Answer (score -1):

It's right there under **Download** on the site you provided yourself

[Daemon Downloads](http://commons.apache.org/downloads/download_daemon.cgi)

Comment: Actually it's not. That download doesn't contain procrun.